# Boto3 in Python - compressing an SVG image when serving in cloudfront using an s3 bucket

Tags: python, svg, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

I want to serve a compressed SVG image (gzipped) on my website.
I have enabled compression behavior on my folder in cloudfront.

I upload the svg to my bucket using boto3 in python like so:

```
s3_resource.Bucket(os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')).put_object(Key=s3_bucket_key, Body=SVG_image, ACL='public-read',ContentType='image/svg+xml')
```

Now I am not sure if the file is actually compressed when it served.

I thought about compressing the svg when I upload it to the S3 bucket to begin with. I have tried two options, both of them do not work(The website crashes when requesting the image).

The error is:
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

It is obvious there is a decoding issue. But why?
This is how I tried to upload the gzipped svg image (both caused the same error)

First try

```
s3_resource.Bucket(os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET_NAMEING')).put_object(Key=s3_bucket_key, Body=monKey_SVG_image, ACL='public-read',ContentType='image/svg+xml', ContentEncoding='gzip')
```

Second try

```
s3_resource.Bucket(os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET_NAMEING')).put_object(Key=s3_bucket_key, Body=monKey_SVG_image, ACL='public-read',ContentType='image/svg+xml', ContentEncoding='Accept-Encoding: gzip')
```